# I want to kill all processes that result from the following command

Tags: process, kill, ps

The following command will display all the PID's running for `vmstat1`:

```
ps -ef | grep "vmstat 1" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

My question is, how do I kill them all, if there's like 20 of them at once?

Comment: have you looked at pkill?

Comment: Couldn't you use `kill $(pidof vmstat)` or `pidof vmstat | xargs kill`?

Comment: @Kotte I don't seem to have the 'pidof' command, as I'm currently running this on a Solaris box.

Comment: Can `$ killall vmstat` not do it for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your command produces list of PIDs, then simply pipe it into:

```
xargs kill
```

Note that your command will match the grep command as well, so consider adding something like `|grep -v grep` before the original `grep` command.

Comment: Another idiom to avoid having the grep itself in the list is to use "grep '[f]oo'" instead of "grep 'foo'". Can't type backquotes on this android keypad, annoyingly.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `pkill`. Though not a standard command, it is found in many Unices and is dedicated to this kind of tasks.

```
pkill -f 'vmstat 1'
```

Also note that your `grep` will match `vmstat 1` but also `vmstat 10` and `grep vmstat 1` (so would that `pkill` above), and `awk` is a superset of `grep`. To be more robust, you could do instead:

```
ps -Ao pid,args | awk '$2 == "vmstat" && $3 == "1" {print $1}' | xargs kill
```

Or

```
pkill -xf 'vmstat 1'
```

Comment: Just use pkill… if you have it! I AM L may not be running Linux.

Comment: @Gilles. pkill is not a Linux invention. I believe it originated in Solaris and it is also found at least in FreeBSD, NetBSD. But it's true it's not a standard command, I'll add the note.

Comment: “The pkill and pgrep utilities first appeared in NetBSD 1.6.  They are modelled after utilities of the same name that appeared in Sun Solaris 7. They made their first appearance in FreeBSD 5.3.” Also OpenBSD 3.5. Quickly made its way into Linux. Not de facto standard because it is missing from OSX.

Comment: pkill actually isn't a bad idea either, tried it and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using awk, you can do

```
ps -ef | grep "vmstat 1" | awk '!/grep/{ print "kill " $2 }' | bash
```

It will output a list of kill commands, and as every one of the commands kills a single process, you will not run into potential argument list too long (though it's highly unlikely when going over running processes), and I added a pattern to avoid matching the grep process itself, as killing it may cut your list short.

Comment: You can (and should) get rid of grep in this case: `ps -ef | awk '/vmstat 1/ { print "kill " $2 }' | bash`

Comment: The "!/grep/" gets rid of grep.

Comment: You don't have to use grep command at all in this case.

Answer (score -1):

As simple as:

```
$ kill -9 $(pgrep -f vmstat)
```

Comment: Looks like the stackexchange formatter turned your backticks into code, making for a misleading answer. You might have intended: `kill -9 $(pgrep -f vmstat)`